# Apache doesn't let Flask app create file

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to get a JPEG image from an app to another. Where I'm receiving it, the stream comes on the request's body and I try to make the file whole again, like this:

```
if r.status_code == 200:
    f = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "\\static\\tmp\\" + filename), 'wb')
    f.write(r.content)
    f.close()
    return True
```

which works just fine when running in localhost. The file is in its place and just like it was when I uploaded it.

When I went to deploy all the apps and test them, Apache didn't allow me to do `f = open(...)`, giving me the error:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/var/www/my_url\\static\\tmp\\2378687.jpeg'
```

And that's strange, because the **tmp** folder has the attributes

```
unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
```

Shouldn't it allow me to create the new file, even not being the sudo user?

Comment: you are not writing to the tmp folder. `\\` is not the directory separator on linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) instead of `\\`. This make your code more portable between linux/windows os.

   `f = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__), "static,"tmp" , filename), 'wb')`
2. you are not referring to /tmp, instead you are trying to write in static folder: `/var/www/my_url`. Try to use absolute path for this.

Comment: This fixed it. I totally forgot about the slashes. The file doesn't open though, as it was somehow corrupted. But it probably has nothing to do with Apache. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug in line the very first line of your function. It should be

```
f = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__),
                      "static", "tmp", filename), 'wb')
```

The directory separator is different on Windows and Linux. That is why it works locally, but not on the server. The `os` module is there to abstract away those differences, but you don't actually use it to construct your filename. The way your code is written, the `os.path.join()` is a noop.

Your code tries to write a file named `my_url\static\tmp\2378687.jpeg` to the directory `/var/www/my_url`.

Also, you should use a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with), probably a configurable constant for the file path and catching errors would be good idea, too:

```
UPLOAD_DIR = '/var/www/my_url/static/tmp'

if r.status_code == 200:
    try:
        with open(os.path.join(UPLOAD_DIR, filename), 'wb') as f
            f.write(r.content)
    except IOError as e:
        # log e.message or something
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: It is a good good idea to try and catch exceptions, thanks for the suggestion. I won't fix the "UPLOAD_DIR" since I'd have to change a lot of code, and for now this will do.